# Saving Pyspark DataFrame directly to FTP withoun saving it locally

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, ftp

I'm trying to load table to ftp as csv, but without saving it locally.I've tried saving it to buffer, but it didn't work out. Is there any solution to this at all?

Here is example of code I've tried

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import io
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
df =  spark.read.table(prod.table")
```

Try 1

```
file_buffer = io.StringIO
ftp.storbinary(df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv('table'), file_buffer)
```

Try 2

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv(file_buffer)
```

First try give me error EOF, second one 'type' object is not iterable. Maybe there is solution with SparkFiles.addFile, but it change name of file

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thank you! Coverting to pandas df worked